# How to persist Map with subMap into table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have entity with id and map with map inside:

```
@Data
public class Item {
   Long id;
   Map<String, Map <String, String> params;
}
```

how to persist **params** into single separate table with using hiberante:

```
id, item_id,      string,              string,                  string
 1      1    ValueFromOuterMap      key1FromInnerMap      value1FromInnerMap
 2      1    ValueFromOuterMap      key2FromInnerMap      value2FromInnerMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Dig into @ElementCollection and (@CollectionTable, @MapKeyJoinColumn) for adjustments.